# unable to close popup window while automating saksfifthavenue.com using selenium webdriver junit test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
public class TestScript {

    protected WebDriver driver;


@Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to(new URL("http://www.saksfifthavenue.com"));

    }

 @Test

    public void Test1(){



       String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
//even without using windowhandle the same thing happens. can't locate the popup

        WebElement closePopUp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1][@id='close-button']"));
        closePopUp.click();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The popup which is appearing is a modal and not a window, so you don't need to get windowHandle. Also, the xpath for close window is incorrect. Use id for locating the close button as follows:

```
WebElement closePopUp = driver.findElement(By.id("closeButton"));
closePopUp.click();
```

Prefer using Id and Css selectors for locating an element. Also, on a side note windowHandle is used if you need to switch to a window or get detail of that window.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Forgot to mention I have tried using id and css too but it didn't work.

Comment: @MAlam - I tried this on firefox 48 with geckodriver v0.10.0, it worked. What is the error you are getting and at what point your code is failing? Also, what selectors did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    // Checking Alert is present and switchTo;
    Alert alert = new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    // Dismiss alert - this will close the alert
    alert.dismiss();
    //Switching to default content after alert is closed
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```